# OpenTripPlanner rest api request

Tags: routing, opentripplanner

following [this tutorial](https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner/wiki/Minimal-Introduction) I set up a OpenTripPlanner (version 0.11.0) stand alone server.
It works very well at

```
 http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

and for example at

```
http://localhost:8080/otp/routers/default/index/routes
```

returns a routes json.

Now I'd make rest api request (I'm interesting to Isochrone api).
I try return isochrone geometry as a set of GeoJSON polygons at the url specified at [this link](http://docs.opentripplanner.org/apidoc/0.11.0/resource_LIsochrone.html) but doesn't work.

Can you suggest the right url to get Isochrone GeoJSON?

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty much in the same boat as [you](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168054/open-trip-planner-tutorial) but I think I have figured out how to create an isochrone. I am using version 0.18.0, not sure if that is relevant or not.

Here is where I found the [example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/opentripplanner-users/fromplace/opentripplanner-users/zrU89JWC61E/7BosE6mU_QUJ)

Here's a sample isochrone that I got

```
http://localhost:8080/otp/routers/default/isochrone?&fromPlace=39.78,-86.1476&date=2015/01/09&time=12:00:00&mode=WALK&&walkSpeed=5&cutoffSec=4000
```

It looks pretty intuitive, but I don't think the docs that I found are up to date so I have no idea how to alter the isochrone except in simple ways. Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is very important what **version of OTP** you use as the developers are constantly making changes - I've only recently been digging into [v0.19](http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/) and below are two example work-in-progress wrappers of calling OTP's isochrone API with it.

@Ravi has already given you the URL call for the isochrone API, if it doesn't work when you update the Lat/Lon for your area and enter it in your browser after launching OTP then go back to the [basics](http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Basic-Usage/) and make sure your instance of OTP works - note OTP's response to the URL will be different if you include the `--analyst` flag (returns GeoJSON) or not (returns a shapefile) when launching OTP. I added a handful of links that have been helpful for me to [@Ravi's post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168054/open-trip-planner-tutorial/180654#180654) about OTP tutorials.

In terms of using the response below are two options that are hopefully helpful.

First, here's a Python function headed in the same direction as the below SQL query (note it just writes out the returning GeoJSON as I haven't taken the time yet to extract/read the response in Python) - I imagine some variation of this is what you'd need for web-mapping (clearly depending on what language your site's analysis is in, guess it'd be even more straightforward in javascript), but I haven't looked for examples (FYI looks like there *was* a [web site](http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Deployments/?highlight=isochrone) that used OTP to create isochrones)

```python
import json, requests
def OTPIsochroneAPI(orig, o_code, depTime = '8:00:00', cutoff = 2700, interimFolder = './interim_isochrones'):
    # create query
    baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/otp/routers/default/isochrone?'
    qryDT = '&date=2015/12/7&time={0}&mode=WALK,TRANSIT&cutoffSec={1}'.format(depTime, cutoff)
    url = '{0}fromPlace={1},{2}&{3}'.format(baseURL, orig.lat, orig.lon, qryDT)
    # print url # print out for testing
    # get isochrone response
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        #print 'response received for %s' % (str(o_code))
    # save out response
        isoFile = '{0}/isochrone_{1}_8am.geojson'.format(interimFolder, (str(o_code)))
        with open(isoFile, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
        # TO DO: return data (plus parse and reformat for some Python spatial library) 
        print 'wrote GeoJSON for o_code %s' % (o_code)
    except IOError as (errno, strerror):
        print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
    except ValueError:
        print "No JSON object could be decoded"
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        raise
```

Alternatively, if you're comfortable in PostGIS here's an approach I got working yesterday, note it requires Paul Ramsey's [HTTP extension](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http) to be installed on your database and I only tested this on the most recent (9.5) PostgreSQL with PostGIS 2.2. Also note this is only meant to extract a **single isochrone** (so only one `&cutoffSec=` given), it would need to be adapted to extract multiple - I think with `unnest()` in place of (or addition to?) the `json_array_elements()` function

```sql
SELECT q.id_column, 
    CASE WHEN (q.resp).status = 200 -- check if response is OK
    THEN ST_SetSRID( -- creating a new geometry so need to set SRID
        ST_GeomFromGeoJSON( --OTP analyst responds with a GeoJSON
          -- but ST_GeomFromGeoJSON only handles a feature at a time 
          -- so we need to extract it, thus the functional but messy SQL below
        (json_array_elements( 
        (q.resp).content::JSON->'features')->'geometry')::text)
        ,4326) 
    ELSE NULL -- there was a problem. maybe your origin was in the ocean
    END as geom_isochrone -- name your extracted geometry column
FROM ( SELECT id_column, -- grab a column identifier, then extract API response:
    http_get('http://localhost:8080/otp/routers/default/isochrone?fromPlace=' 
    || y || ',' || x || -- set your lat and lon from input data
    '&date=2015/12/7&time=8:00:00&mode=WALK,TRANSIT&cutoffSec=2700') as resp 
    FROM input_table -- your input table
) q;
```