# Open Trip Planner Tutorial

Tags: references, opentripplanner

I was wondering if anyone had a good tutorial for Open Trip Planner. I am not an experienced programmer and I am having a lot of trouble understanding what the documentation wants me to do. I got through [basic usage](http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Basic-Usage/), but after that I became very confused.  For example, I think the next relevant section is configuration. The first paragraph is about build directories. What exactly is a build directory? I've looked all over the internet for, but I didn't see any tutorials, and only a handful of stack overflow/exchange questions.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a tutorial on using OTP that might be useful:

https://github.com/marcusyoung/otp-tutorial

It's aimed at beginner/intermediate users of OTP (setting up and query an OTP instance, automation using some R functions) rather than developers looking to amend OTP code.

Marcus

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; I have not seen full tutorials, but below are links I've found useful in my own exploration.

As far as I can tell OTP is under heavy development and won't flesh out documentation until all the underlying functionality is solid and they're ready for a v1.0 release.

Trolling through their [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/opentripplanner-users) the general theme of response to inquiries on "how to do X" involves learning to program in Java to write your own analysis calling OTP classes/objects. One notable exception is where the ScriptingAPI author cleaned up a replicable [travel time matrix repository](https://github.com/laurentg/otp-travel-time-matrix) based on [this user's cut](https://github.com/rafapereirabr/otp-travel-time-matrix) which shows how to use Jython scripting to calculate a travel time matrix.

To your question about build directories my current understanding is it is just the directory structure laid out in the [Routing section](http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Configuration/#routers) of the configuration page, and I think the main things to know are:

- OTP's home directory (where the `otp-...jar` file lives), default is `/var/otp` on Linux machines (when you build the graph you can set this to wherever you want by adding `--basePath [home-directory]`)
- the graph directory, which defaults to `[home-directory]/graphs` but you can similarly set with a `--graphs /path/to/graphs` flag when launching OTP
- the router directory, which defaults to `[graphs-directory]/[routerID]` - I think this is technically optional but allows you to have multiple regions and only run OTP for one of them (by setting the `--router '[routerID]'` flag on OTP launch)
- the `build-config.json` file tells OTP what options to set when building the underlying graph, as I'm sure you've seen the configuration page mentions the build-config file but the only complete view I've seen of the options is in the [source code](https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner/blob/2aed1b65a2c7ec5c4c96ba733c2d78da02696aec/src/main/java/org/opentripplanner/standalone/GraphBuilderParameters.java)
- `router-config.json` includes default routing request configurations (walking speed, etc), if it's in your router directory it'll be used when the graph is built

Another useful thing that I saw somewhere in the documentation is running `java -jar otp-0.19.0-shaded.jar --help` will tell you what all flags OTP accepts, which is then useful in searching the source code for functionality